# How to connect Logic App to Dynamics 365 using webhook?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, webhooks, azure-logic-apps, microsoft-dynamics

I have created one logic app and a plugin. I need that logic app to be trigger when request to sent to http trigger by plugin. I use webhook for that but seems like my webhook is not working. I think it is because I am missing authentication thing while registering webhook. URL from logic apps doesn't have "code" which we can use as webhook and but does have sigid. not sure if we can use that

If someone help me in identifying key and value for httpquerystring authentication

Answer (score 0):

To call Http triggered logic app from a webhook, you can use URL generated from Http trigger which will contain SAS token.

- I have created a sample logicapp with Http tigger as shown below,
  [image]
- Save the URL generated from from Http trigger.
- Create another logic App and take Http webhook as trigger.
- Select method as post and give subscribe URL as the URL from the Http Trigger.
  [image]
- When you run webhook logic App, Http trigger will run automatically. Below is the image for Http trigger which is triggered when i run Webhook.

  [image]
- Alternatively, if you don't want to use two logic apps you can call the URL generated from Http trigger from your plugin. This will not cause authentication issue as it contains SAS token in URL.